# How to test in different devices in online for apk?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any software providing to test for all device or any online emulators to test apk?

As my emulator is too slow to launch and display, is there any other software providing apk to run and test in all version emulator. Suggest some software please. I searched in google but I couldn't find better and best one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different other emulators. I suggest two different emulators you could use.

Bluestacks : http://www.bluestacks.com/

Genymotion : http://www.genymotion.com/#

I have heard only positive reactions about both, so you should try them out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google's emulator for testing, have you enabled Intel HAXM? You can download this through the android SDK manager (it is the last check box in the Extras section). This will significantly increase the speed of your AVD on Windows and MacOS. If you are running Linux, then make sure you have enabled KVM and have added the -enable-kvm parameter when you start your AVD.

Can you also be more specific regarding your test criteria? For example, do you need to test against all existing versions of Android? What about display resolution/density? Are you using any automation framework?

If you need to test in parallel on multiple device configurations, then I would recommend taking a look at this blog: [How to run the Android Emulator (with Hardware Acceleration) on Amazon EC2 and Google Cloud](http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/android-emulator-on-amazon-ec2-and-google-cloud/). This way you can spin up multiple AVDs in parallel without worrying about hardware.

Hope this helps.